# Программная установка названия переменной

Tags: c#, строки, list

Нужно инициализировать List с названием, взятым из параметра метода.
Как-то так:

```
public void CreateList(string name)
{
    List<string> name = new List<string>();
}
```

То есть, чтобы название списка было таким, какую строку я передаю в параметре этого метода. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Что?Зачем?Откуда вы такие идеи берете?

Comment: Опишите подробнее Вашу проблему

Comment: Это не проблема, а, скорее, удобство. Нужно отсортировать слова по совпадающим в них буквам со всевозможными комбинациями. Если называть списки "говорящими именами", это упростило бы задачу

Comment: Удобство - это делать метод, который отвечает за что то одно, а не как вы ходите работать с неизвестной коллекцией...

Comment: Сделайте словарь списков и не мучайтесь

Comment: Да, словарь, пожалуй, лучшее решение. Спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

public void CreateList(string name)
{
    dictionary[name] = new List<string>();
}

public void UseList()
{
    var dic = dictionary.OrderBy(d => d.Key); // for example
    // use dic
}
```